# Celery with RabbitMQ: AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'

Tags: python, celery

I'm running the [First Steps with Celery Tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html).

We define the following task:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Then call it:

```
>>> from tasks import add
>>> add.delay(4, 4)
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
```

I'm running both the celery worker and the rabbit-mq server. Rather strangely, celery worker reports the task as succeeding:

```
[2014-04-22 19:12:03,608: INFO/MainProcess] Task test_celery.add[168c7d96-e41a-41c9-80f5-50b24dcaff73] succeeded in 0.000435483998444s: 19
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: As a new user of Celery and RabbitMQ (or any library you want to learn) seeing errors when following a tutorial doesn't inspire confidence in the quality of the software.  It is just plain frustrating.  

I want to learn how to use your library, not its workarounds.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just keep reading tutorial. It will be explained in [Keep Results](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results) chapter.

To start Celery you need to provide just broker parameter, which is required to send messages about tasks. If you want to retrieve information about state and results returned by finished tasks you need to set backend parameter. You can find full list with description in [Configuration docs: CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_backend).

Comment: I didn't have any trouble following the tutorial, but still ran into this error and had a hard time correcting it. I was running Celery in one Ubuntu terminal window, and the Python interpreter in a second. In the first window, I added backend='rpc://' and restarted Celery. But Python, in the second window, wasn't aware of this change. After I pressed Ctrl+d to kill Python, and started Python again, it worked fine.

Comment: I get a 404 with the last link in your answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've updated link. However, Celery v4 has changed settings here, so proceed with caution.

Comment: @SteveSaporta Very helpful comment! This little details should be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: The problem here is that you *shouldn't* need to specify a `result_backend` to simply return an `AsyncResult` instance.  (This is what is returned by `.delay()`.)  The `result_backend` should only be necessary to look at attributes of that result, such as `.status`.

Comment: I use Redis as broker, and this problem doesn't present itself.  (I can run/call tasks fine without a `result_backend`.)  But if this is still the case for amqp, I would call that a bug.  Calling a task itself shouldn't require a `result_backend` specified.

Comment: for celery backend you should use redis, because rabbitmq is not supported as a backend https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6384

Answer (score 48):

I suggest having a look at:
http://www.cnblogs.com/fangwenyu/p/3625830.html

There you will see that
instead of

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
```

you should be writing

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
```

This is it.

Answer (score 27):

In case anyone made the same easy to make mistake as I did:  The tutorial doesn't say so explicitly, but the line

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://')
```

is an EDIT of the line in your `tasks.py` file.  Mine now reads:

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
```

When I run python from the command line I get:

```
$ python
>>> from tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(4,50)
>>> result.ready()
>>> False
```

All tutorials should be easy to follow, even when a little drunk.  So far this one doesn't reach that bar.

Comment: well, when you follow the tutorial, pls remember that after editing the tasks.py you must also reimport the add function from tasks module! Basically despite correct backend assignment in add() I kept getting this error until I quit Python in the console (>>>quit()), got back to it ($python) and retyped from tasks import add.

Comment: Aggree, a bad tutorial.

Comment: Well, it still is confusing after +5 years! I just opened up a [pull-request](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/6979) and added a new sentence to fix this

Answer (score 7):

What is not clear by the tutorial is that the tasks.py module needs to be edited so that you change the line:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')
```

to include the RPC result backend:

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://')
```

Once done, <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> the celery worker process and restart it:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

The tutorial is confusing in that we're making the assumption that creation of the app object is done in the client testing session, which it is not.

Comment: This got me unstuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your project directory find the settings file.

Then run the below command in your terminal:

```bash
sudo vim settings.py
```

copy/paste the below config into your `settings.py`:

```py
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
```

Note: This is your backend for storing the messages in the queue if you are using `django-celery` package for your Django project.

Comment: I had this issue when removing backend_result=rpc (i.e. relying on the default result backend, which is none), and then repeatedly calling result.ready()

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error by adding app after taskID:

```
response = AsyncResult(taskID, app=celery_app)

where celery_app = Celery('ANYTHING', broker=BROKER_URL, backend=BACKEND_URL )
```

if you want to get the status of the celery task to know whether it is `"PENDING","SUCCESS","FAILURE"`

```
status = response.status
```

Answer (score 1):

Celery rely both on a backend AND a broker.
This solved it for me using only Redis:

```
app = Celery("tasks", backend='redis://localhost',broker="redis://localhost")
```

Remember to restart worker in your terminal after changing the config

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when trying to use `celery.AsyncResult`. My fix was to make sure I use the actual instance running with my application rather than the overall `celery` package.

```py
from celery import Celery
app = Celery("tasks")

...

result = app.AsyncResult(task_id=1234)
```

May just be relevant because I'm trying to read the AsyncResult from a different application than the workers, but I can't imagine that's too rare of a use case.

Answer (score 0):

My case was simple - I used interactive Python console and Python cached imported module. I killed console and started it again - everything works as it should.

```py
import celery


app = celery.Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379',
                    backend='mongodb://localhost:27017/celery_tasks')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

In Python console.

```py
>>> from tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(4, 4)
>>> result.ready()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching from Windows to Linux solved the issue for me
Windows is not guaranteed to work, it's mentioned [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4178#issuecomment-321070667)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when integrating celery with django, and wanted to get back the task status from django API. Finally it turned out I had to provide **CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND** in the **main django project settings.py**.

Details of integration in the link https://xeon2k.wordpress.com/2024/01/03/celery-task-status-via-django-api/

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue, what resolved it for me was to import the celery file (celery.py) in the init function of you're app with something like:

```
from .celery import CELERY_APP as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

if you use a celery.py file as described [here](https://medium.com/swlh/python-developers-celery-is-a-must-learn-technology-heres-how-to-get-started-578f5d63fab3)