# need to restart python while applying Celery config

Tags: python, ipython, celery

That's a small story...

I had this error:

> AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'

When changed tasks.py, like Diederik said at [Celery with RabbitMQ: AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215311/celery-with-rabbitmq-attributeerror-disabledbackend-object-has-no-attribute/39997411#39997411)

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
```

ran it

```
>>> from tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(4,50)
>>> result.ready()
```

got DisabledBackend again ... hmm what was that..

put code to file run.py and it returned True...

```
from tasks import add
try:
        result = add.delay(1,4)
        print (result.ready())
except:
        print "exept"
```

I see that if I call >>> from tasks import add after tasks.py changed, it doesn't get the updates... That behaviour is the same for ipython, so because of I can't understand the reason, I advice people to DEBUG from scripts like ~runthis.py

Will be glad for answer which will smash my idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the interpreter, you need to

```
reload(tasks)
```

this will force reimport tasks module

Comment: It detailed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534480/proper-way-to-reload-a-python-module-from-the-console